# Read JSON Data in Python

Tags: json, python-3.5

I have a input file which contains a sequence(not necessarily a list/tuple etc..) of JSON elements.

This is the sample data:

```
{
             "candidate":[
                {
                   "id":"25624",
                   "name":"Clinton",
                   "affiliation":"Democrat",
                   "color":"",
                   "value":"46.8",
                   "status":"1"
                },
                {
                   "id":"25623",
                   "name":"Trump",
                   "affiliation":"Republican",
                   "color":"",
                   "value":"43.6",
                   "status":"1"
                }
             ],
             "date":"Tue, 08 Nov 2016 00:00:00 -0600" }, {
             "candidate":[
                {
                   "id":"25624",
                   "name":"Clinton",
                   "affiliation":"Democrat",
                   "color":"",
                   "value":"47.0",
                   "status":"1"
                },
                {
                   "id":"25623",
                   "name":"Trump",
                   "affiliation":"Republican",
                   "color":"",
                   "value":"43.8",
                   "status":"1"
                }
             ],
             "date":"Mon, 07 Nov 2016 00:00:00 -0600" }
```

I am trying to use JSON library which can read first block of JSON but errs out when reading multiple blocks.

What is the right way to read multiple JSON elements in Python.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Making them as an array of JSON objects?

Comment: Is there a way to convert the entire file to array of Json objects. Any pointers would be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you would like to do is create a generator function and take advantage of how json has been implemented in Python. Here is my working example with a generator function:

```
import json
from splitstream import splitfile

def generate_json(file_name):
    for jsonstr in splitfile(open(file_name), format="json"):
        yield json.loads(jsonstr)

for item in generate_json('data.json'):
    print item
```

However, you might need to install splitstream (through pip) and include the generator function generate_json in your code. What this function does is yield(return) a json object everytime it is completed.

Comment: In your function, jsonstr is returned as bytes. json.loads is not able to process bytes, returns error message:  "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "read_polls.py", line 11, in <module>
    for item in generate_json('testData.json'):
  File "read_polls.py", line 9, in generate_json
    yield json.loads(jsonstr)
  File "/Users/ayada/anaconda/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py", line 312, in loads
    s.__class__.__name__))
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'"

Comment: I would like to understand what's the type of jsonstr in your function. I am using Python 3.5

Comment: str(jsonstr,'utf-8'), cnverted bytes to String. The solution worked neat. Thanks!!